# Apply deletes during custom seed of DbSet<T>

Tags: c#, linq, generics, reflection, entity-framework-core

I am trying to extend my custom seed routine (I know EF Core 2.1 supports seeding natively, but I have a [blocker](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/13154) in converting) to apply deletions. If a record exists in the database, but no longer in the seed data, I want to delete it. Rather than writing a custom delete routine for each `DbSet`, I am trying to implement with generics (and possibly reflection if needed).

My first attempt:

```
private static void Delete<TEntity>(DbContext dbContext, IEnumerable<TEntity> seedRows) where TEntity : class, IBaseEntity
{
    var toRemove = dbContext.Set<TEntity>().Except(seedRows);
    dbContext.RemoveRange(toRemove);
    dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

However, since `TEntity` contains some properties that are null in the seed data (such as timestamps generated on add), I can't compare the entire entities in the `Except()` call (with the default equality comparer, anyway). I really only care about comparing the primary key.

My work in progress for addressing this issue is below. `TEntity` could have a primary key of a simple `Id` column, or it could be a many-to-many mapping with a complex primary key of two `<EntityName>Id`s. `IBaseEntity` currently does not have any `Id`/primary key information since it is implemented both by basic entities as well as many-to-many/junction entities.

```
private static void Delete<TEntity>(DbContext dbContext, IEnumerable<TEntity> seedRows) where TEntity : class, IBaseEntity
{
    var idProperties = typeof(TEntity).GetProperties().Where(p => p.Name.Contains("Id"));
    var toRemove = dbContext.Set<TEntity>().Select(s => idProperties).Except(seedRows.Select(s => idProperties));
    dbContext.RemoveRange(toRemove);
    dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

[full source/context](https://github.com/collinbarrett/FilterLists/commit/c9628a2aefa179c1f95ed66a2ecbea72c1a8f22c)

The two instances of `.Select(s => idProperties)`, however, obviously do not work. Is there a way to select the `Id` properties (or, alternatively, the primary key) of a `DbSet<T>` to be used in the `Except()` comparer? I am open to a completely different approach as well, since I feel like I am off in the weeds.

Comment: Maybe you can create interface like IEntityWithKey with one property that will be your id. Just inherit all entities from that interface

Comment: @Ihor I thought about that, and I think it would work for basic entities. But, how would I make that work for many-to-many/junction entities whose primary key is a composite of two unknown `<EntityName>Id`s? I don't know how to make those many-to-many entities implement this proposed interface since the property names would be different.

Comment: There is no need of interfaces because `DbContext` contains all the necessary metadata, including the PK mapping. However checking for existence by more than one property is not easy. Note that EF (Core) requires entities to be loaded in the context in order to be deleted. Your attempt loads the whole table in memory, is this acceptable?

Comment: @IvanStoev Thanks, that makes sense. Yes, in this case, the seed happens once on app boot and deals with relatively small datasets. So, loading into memory is acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF Core metadata provides all the necessary information needed.

Instead of reflection, you can use `Expression` class to dynamically build criteria like this (pseudocode):

```
(seedRows1.Key1 == e.Key1 && seedRows1.Key2 == e.Key2 ... && seeedRows1.KeyM == e.KeyM)
||
(seedRows2.Key1 == e.Key1 && seedRows2.Key2 == e.Key2 ... && seeedRows2.KeyM == e.KeyM)
...
||
(seedRowsN.Key1 == e.Key1 && seedRowsN.Key2 == e.Key2 ... && seeedRowsN.KeyM == e.KeyM);
```

which would return the matching items from the db. To get the non matching items, the criteria can simply be inverted and used as predicate for deleting. Note that for the single PK this would translate to `NOT IN (...)` SQL criteria.

Putting it into action:

```
private static void Delete<TEntity>(DbContext dbContext, IEnumerable<TEntity> seedRows)
    where TEntity : class//, IBaseEntity
{
    var entityType = dbContext.Model.FindEntityType(typeof(TEntity));
    var entityPK = entityType.FindPrimaryKey();
    var dbEntity = Expression.Parameter(entityType.ClrType, "e");
    Expression matchAny = null;
    foreach (var entity in seedRows)
    {
        var match = entityPK.Properties
            .Select(p => Expression.Equal(
                Expression.Property(dbEntity, p.PropertyInfo),
                Expression.Property(Expression.Constant(entity), p.PropertyInfo)))
            .Aggregate(Expression.AndAlso);
        matchAny = matchAny != null ? Expression.OrElse(matchAny, match) : match;
    }
    var dbQuery = dbContext.Set<TEntity>().AsQueryable();
    if (matchAny != null)
    {
        var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(Expression.Not(matchAny), dbEntity);
        dbQuery = dbQuery.Where(predicate);
    }
    var dbEntities = dbQuery.ToList();
    if (dbEntities.Count == 0) return;
    dbContext.RemoveRange(dbEntities);
    dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Wow, I'm going to be staring at this for some time wrapping my head around it. But, initial testing seems to confirm that it works. I've never used the Expression class (in a static context) before. I have some reading to do. Thanks.